# move between lines by first letter in vim

Tags: vim

is there any way to move between lines by first letter in vim as we usually did  by using the "f+letter" in the current line, Example:

```
 din          (tuple_hash_ack_data),       
 wr_en        (tuple_hash_ack_wr),        
 dout         (ack_fifo_data),       
 rd_en        (ack_fifo_rd),       
 empty        (ack_fifo_empty),        
 data_count   (tuple_hash_count),      
 almost_full  (tuple_hash_almost_full)
```

At first the cursor is stop at the first line:

```
   din          (tuple_hash_ack_data),
```

I want to jump to the line:

```
   almost_full  (tuple_hash_almost_full)
```

I want to type something like "fa", is it possible?

Comment: What's wrong with `/^a`?

Comment: I am not sure if this is an answer or comment, so I just put it here. I suggest you try the plugin easyMotion. With this plugin you could move to any letter/character or word on your screen very fast.

Answer (score 6):

`/^a` will get you to the next line starting with "a"- in regular expression syntax, `^` matches the start of a line, so `/^a` searches for the start of a line, immediately followed by a.

Answer (score 1):

Especially with `:set relativenumber`, navigating to the start of a nearby line can be done via `[count]_` (down) and `[count]-` (up). Note that commands like `j` and `k` can be prefixed with a `[count]`, too.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to moving in the window you should give the plugin [preciseJump](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3437)
a chance.
I use it with the mappings:

```
nnoremap ,f :call PreciseJumpF(-1, -1, 0)<CR>
vnoremap ,f <ESC>:call PreciseJumpF(-1, -1, 1)<CR>
onoremap ,f :call PreciseJumpF(-1, -1, 0)<CR>
```

so I type `,f` followed by a char and all occurrences of that char are highlighted. I just type the corresponding char and the cursor jumps there.